# central limit theorem, solving for probability

Tags: probability

I am playing a game and am trying to calculate the probability that I will win at 40,000 or more points total, if I play the game 1,000,000 times. The expected value for one game is zero and the variance is 20,000.

To solve this, first I calculated the expected value and variance for 1 million games. The expected value would be 0 and the variance would be 20,000,000,000 (due to linearity of expectation and variance). The standard deviation (sd) would be the sqrt of the variance.

I believe the next step would be to assume that the distribution is normal (according to CLT), calculate the z score and then look at the normal distribution table for my z-score. However, I see two different formulas online and I'm not sure which one is correct to calculate the z-score in this scenario.

First I saw x - u/ (sd/sqrt(n)), then I saw x-u/sd.

The first formula gives me almost a z-score of 282, which seems crazy. I would then subtract the probability from 1, since i want the probability accumulated to the right. Then, this first formula gives me 0% chance, and the second formula gives me about a 40% chance (assuming I did everything correctly).

I feel like 0% chance could make sense, since my expected value is 0. It would not be likely for me to get 40,000 points, when 0 is expected, although the variance is quite high.

Which formula is the correct one? Are they used for different situations, such as sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard error of the mean winnings in $N$ games is $\sigma/\sqrt{N}$, where $\sigma$ is the SD of the winnings on a single game. But you are interested in the sum of the winnings which has SD $\sigma\sqrt{N}$.

So in $N=1,000,000$ games each with expected winnings $\mu=0$ and SD $\sigma=200$ the total winnings is approximately normally distributed with mean $\mu_{sum}=N\mu=0$ and standard deviation $\sigma_{sum}=\sqrt{N}\sigma=200,000$. Then the $z$-score corresponding to total winnings of $20,000$ is $0.1$ which gives a probability of winning $20,000$ or less of $\approx 0.54$ and so a probability of winning more than this of $\approx 0.46$

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your first attempt actually looked at the expected value of the sum of many games (or at least it looks that way from your result as you did not give your method). This is not what you want as you are looking for over 20,000 in a single game.

CLT says that the expected mean value from infinite convolution (or draws) from an identical distribution will produce a gaussian distribution, with mean of the original distribution and variance of the original distribution.

I propose a much simpler solution - assuming the distribution over your outcomes is gaussian, with zero mean and variance 20,000, standard deviation of $100\sqrt{2}$. You want to know the probability that you get over 40,000 in at least a single game. The easier way to compute this is the probability that you wont *not* get over 40,000 in a single game.

For each game (yes the z-score is 283, perhaps you confused your initial variance with with what should have been you initial standard deviation)

$$P(x < 40,000) =  1 - 4.3545917 \times 10^{-17394}$$

Playing the game 1,000,000 is $P(x < 40,000)^{1,000,000}$ is still very close to 1 and so it would look like you are very very unlikely to get that score in a million tries.

*However,* this changes if you actually meant your standard deviation was 20,000. Then,

$$P(x < 40,000) =  1 - 0.02275 = 0.97725$$

So,

$$P(x < 40,000)^{1000000} = 4.776 \times 10^{-9995}$$

So you are basically guaranteed you will get over 40,000 in at least one of the games.

**EDIT:**

From @tara's comment I see there was a misunderstanding.

You were right about central limit theorem! When drawing from multiple normal distributions the variance grows as $n\sigma^2$, or you can say the standard deviation grows as $\sqrt{n}\sigma$. This is where the error is. You had said $z =\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$, but it should have been $z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma \times \sqrt{n}}$. So the standard deviation is 141421.356237 (ie $\sigma \times \sqrt{n} = 141421.356237$) and it is zero mean, hence the zscore is roughly 0.2828.

To finish it off we can convert this into a probability and say that there is a 38.8648% chance of your score exceeding 40,000.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was poor-- In each game, I can only get 200 points or so max. However, I can also get scores like -200, so that is why E(X)=0 and V(x) is so high (20,000). I want to know if I sum all the games together, if the total will be more than 40,000.

Comment: Is my approach still incorrect?